# In a NetSuite Saved Search how to I display the id of a join rather than the name?

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

How do I display the internalId of a joined record in a search (It's needed to match up to an external system.) It always displays the name of the record.

It's for this field: {transaction.salesorder}

I tried a formula: CONCAT('#',{transaction.salesorder})
I also tried number formula: {transaction.salesorder}

But I just get errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the internal id for List/Record type fields in a saved search simply by appending `.id` to the field name in a formula. For your example this would mean using `{transaction.salesorder.id}`

HTH.